# How to Insert and display Hindi character in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I have some problem while insert Hindi or any other language characters into database using Grails.

Follow details help you to solve problem.

**I create database using following syntax.**

```
CREATE DATABASE hindi_test
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Table Syntax is,**

```
CREATE TABLE `hindi` (

  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,

  `data` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I also mention `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>` on top of GSP.

But hindi or any other language text are not insert and display properly in GSP.

Comment: try to send to your database query `"SET NAMES utf8"`. I'm not certain but it could be MySQL specific stuff.

Comment: I already set data column as "utf8_unicode_ci".

Comment: Assuming you have set `grails.converters.encoding = 'UTF-8'` and `grails.view.gsp.encoding='UTF-8'`

Comment: @defectus yes I already set this 2 config  in groovy file.

Comment: @007, when I've worked on some Russian php websites in past the only way I can get correct unicode output was `SET NAMES` query from php script after database connection established (even with proper utf8 settings for database and tables themselves). I'm not sure is is true now.